# Programm a loop that goes on until you enter something into console

Tags: java, while-loop, console, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to build a loop, that executes a specific method when I enter text into the console.
I want to use the java.util.Scanner but when I try to use .hasNext() for checking inside if() and then .next() to get the input it waits until I enter something instead of looping on.

```
while(true) {
    main_loop();
}

private void main_loop() {
    do_other_things(); 
    if(sc.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("user entered " + sc.next());
    } else {
        System.out.println("user entered nothing");
    }
}
```

How can I make it output "user entered nothing" until I enter something, so that it outputs "user entered [...]" and then goes on with "user entered nothing"?

Comment: That's how the Scanner works. It waits for a proper input, blocking the thread. I'd recommending making use of a `new Thread()`.

Comment: You will need to use a 2nd thread for this, one to hold a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of another thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                //... user has input
            }
            else {
                //... user does not have input
            }
    }).start();
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a **seperate thread** run to wait for the input then (if you want this to trigger if the user inputs a second string) once it has processed the input, schedule the runnable again.

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String st = scanner.next();
                //do something now the user has inputted
                System.out.printf("The user entered a string! (%s)", st);

                //run the runnable to wait again
                executorService.schedule(this, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }
    };
    executorService.schedule(runnable, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: `executorService.schedule(this, 0, TimeUNit.SECONDS)`, what are the benefits of this over a `while(true)` inside of the thread? (genuine question, I'm quite new to Java's Executor Service)

Comment: You can use either, it is kind of personal preference. However, this gives more flexibility if you wanted to add more features such as a 'cooldown', for which you would change the delay that it re runs the thread. On the other hand, `while (true)` is cleaner. Some consider `while (true)` bad practice and while it does have advantages and disadvantages it is opinion based.

Comment: I just wrote while(true) here... had a boolean value inside, for triggering it to leave from inside.